# Android ExpandableListView with custom group header

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm an Android newbie. I want to create an expandable ListView where 1 row has custom info that has to be specified in the manin thread instead of being hardcoded in a layout.

I want to have an image and 2 textviews in it. I think I will need a custom layout file, but I'm not sure where to make a call for it in my code. Please assist.

What follows is my GropView fxn inside my custom adapter. I want case 0 to load a custom layout file

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean arg1, View convertView,
        ViewGroup arg3) {

    String laptopName = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);
    }
    TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.laptop);
    item.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    item.setText(laptopName);

    this.context = (Activity) context;
    switch (groupPosition) {
    case 0:
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(this.context.getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.dark_blue));
        convertView.inflate(R.layout.first_row_layout, 0, arg3);
        break;
    case 1:
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(this.context.getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.purple));
        break;
    case 2:
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(this.context.getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.green));
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The position in your code  where you define the layout for your group items is this:

```
 if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);
    }
```

In your case you are using the layout R.layout.group_item for your group items. If you want to load different layouts for each group position u need to move this part of your code inside the switch-case. You have to be careful with images inside your ListView, more info about that here:

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html